# Display each value on new lines instead of same using group_concat

Tags: mysql, line-breaks, group-concat

I have the following Query to display the results:

```
SELECT C.Customer_ID
     , group_concat(CP.Company_description separator '\n') as companyName
  FROM tbl_Customer AS C
  JOIN tbl_Company AS CP
    ON (CP.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID)
 group 
    by Customer_ID
```

I am getting the desired result however the results are being displayed as this.

| Customer_ID | companyName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1, test2, test3 |
| 2 | test4, test5, test6 |

I would like the results to display on new lines like this

[Please Click Here to Refer to What I am Looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCivm.png)

so just to be more clear, i was test1, test2, test3 displayed on new line like:

test1

test2

test3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add another column in group. Like this

SELECT C.Customer_ID, CP.Company_description as companyName

FROM tbl_Customer AS C

inner JOIN tbl_Company AS CP

ON (CP.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID)

group by Customer_ID, CP.Company_description

Comment: please can you be more clarify, and how achieves